# Map Series with Page Queries in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, map-series

At work, I create hundreds of maps for mailings that go out to landowners. My layouts are pretty simple and typically only have a map frame, legend, north arrow, scale bar, and a text box with the landowner's name in it.

Currently, I use ArcGIS Pro and do everything manually. I use the definition query to only show the property boundaries for a specific landowner, adjust the view if the parcels are out of frame, and edit the landowner's name in the text box before exporting and saving it as a PDF on my computer. Because this task is so repetitive, I figured there has to be a way to automate the process.

I tried creating a Map Series with Page Query. When setting up the page query, I used the the owner's name as the field to base the pages off of. I also tried using the owner's address since sometimes the owner name's might be slightly different, but the map is being sent to the same address (hence the same landowner). Both of those worked and showed me just one parcel based on those filters, ultimately creating multiple maps for the same owner. Instead, I want to create maps with all the parcels per land owner. In other words, if I have 100 parcels but 5 landowners, I only want 5 maps. When I go look at the index layer within the layout properties of the map series, I put the parcel layer as the layer, owner name as the name field as well as the sort field. I tried using the owner name as the "Group BY" field in the optional fields as well, but none of these settings work.

Is there a way to do that using the map series with page queries? Or would I have to go about it a different way?

Comment: To do this I think you should investigate Map Series with Page Queries.

Comment: You can use dynamic text for the landowners name.

Comment: ArcPy can be great to meet more complex map automation requirements but yours looks ideal for a Map Series using parcels as the index layer.

Comment: @PolyGeo why not add "map series with page queries" as an answer?

Comment: @DanC I think the question is insufficiently focused because it’s an open ended request for references and help with a broad task.

Comment: @PolyGeo I tried your suggestion and it's very close to what I want, thank you for your help! However, is there a way to do the query so that all the parcels with the same landowner are on one map? In other words, if I have 100 parcels but all of those parcels are owned by 5 different owners, is there a way to create the map series so that each page shows all of the specific landowner's parcels?

Comment: The answer to that is yes, but if you need help with how, then please [edit] your question to revise it with what you’ve tried and where you’re currently stuck so that it may be re-opened to receive answers.

Comment: @PolyGeo I edited my post but I am not sure if that automatically re-opens the question.

Comment: It looks like your question was re-opened by the community 10 hours ago. Are you saying that you want one page created for an owner even when their name is spelled in more than one way?  It is the index layer not any page queries that sets the extent of the pages. Page queries only alter what is displayed on a page after its extent has been set.

Comment: @PolyGeo Essentially yes. The owner names are usually the same for each parcel, but sometimes the name might be slightly off (for example, JOHN DOE vs JOHN J DOE). I edited my question to include some more detail about what I have been including within the settings in the index layer within the layout properties for the map series.

Comment: I think you need to unify those spellings.